# Adding value to Lookup columns fails using CSOM in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, development, csom, lookup-column

Using the below code, I am able to update the Publications column but not the Authors column as it returns

> Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are
>   trying to update may be read only.

Is there a more obvious way to work with these columns, I'm constantly guessing a naming convention, etc.

```
        List NewsAlertsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointConnector.sp_NewsAlerts_list);

        // This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
        // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in.                 
        CamlQuery CamlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        string qs = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>{0}</RowLimit><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" Ascending =\"False\"/></OrderBy></Query></View>", 500);
        CamlQuery.ViewXml = qs;

        ListItemCollection z = NewsAlertsList.GetItems(CamlQuery);

        // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
        clientContext.Load(z,
                          items => items.Include(
                           item => item["Publication"],
                           item => item["Author"]));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem oListItem = NewsAlertsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

        oListItem["to"] = newsalert.to;
        oListItem["url"] = newsalert.url;
        oListItem["subject"] = newsalert.subject;
        oListItem["Title"] = newsalert.title;
        oListItem["source"] = newsalert.source;
        oListItem["Category"] = newsalert.categories;
        oListItem["userid"] = newsalert.userid;
        oListItem["comments"] = newsalert.comments;
        oListItem["Language"] = newsalert.language;

        var p = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ADMPANewsAlertsPublications").GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(newsalert.publicationID));
        var a = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ADMPANewsAlertsAuthors").GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(newsalert.authorID));

        oListItem["Publication"] = p;
        oListItem["Author"] = a;

        oListItem.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Seems like you are referencing a 2007 assembly, was this an upgrade project? Try replacing any reference to Microsoft.Sharepoint.Security with the assembly on any 2010 sharepoint server here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI

Comment: I dont have access to the server.  I will update my question because I got this partially working so I have a more specific issue now.

Comment: It turns out the code bove does work, it was my Author Column was for some reason called Author0, once i changed that line, it now updates

Comment: It turns out the code bove does work, it was my Author Column was for some reason called Author0, once i changed that line, it now updates

Answer (score 0):

You can update the People field as follows

Here is working code

```
ListItem item = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("test").GetItemById(6);
item["Author"] = 21;
item.Update();

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

As per this you can update your code as follows

```
oListItem["Publication"] = newsalert.publicationID;
oListItem["Author"] = newsalert.authorID;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how to use this.  I already call the ListItem using 
var a = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ADMPANewsAlertsAuthors").GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(newsalert.authorID)); but for some reasonbn I cannot submit it the same way I do the Publication?  I have to assume there is something in how the Author table is created that is causing this?